# Saving Japanese Text to SQL Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have an asp.net application using which people would be able to insert English,French and Japanese data to MS SQL database. I have made the necessary changes to the DB like having the Fields as NVARCHAR and also puting the 'N' Prefix before the actual parameter (as i am using Stored Procedures).

Either of the fixes are not working, i might be doing something wrong with the Prefix, it would be great if you can help me resolve this :)

The parameters i am using are below:

```
   @RewardId INT = NULL,
  @SupplierId INT = NULL,
  @RewardCode NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
  @RewardDesc NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
  @RStartDate DATETIME = NULL,
  @REndDate DATETIME = NULL,
  @RStatus BIT = NULL,
  @RCostPrice FLOAT = NULL,
  @PDCost FLOAT = NULL,
  @RStocks INT = NULL,
  @RewardTypeId INT = NULL,
  @RCategoryId INT = NULL,
  @RProductDesc NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
  @RTermsCond NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
  @DMId INT = NULL,
  @RRetailPrice FLOAT = NULL,
  @TemplateId INT = NULL,
  @RFreight FLOAT = NULL,
  @RTotalCost FLOAT = NULL,
  @MinimumQuantity INT = NULL,
  @RewardImageURL nvarchar(500) = null,
  @UpdateDate nvarchar(50) = null,
  @Rpoints nvarchar(50) = null  ,
   @ExpiryDateSetup nvarchar(50),
    @ExpiryNumberOfMonths nvarchar(50),
    @minimumstockcount int = NULL,
    @RewardRelationId int = null,
    @ParentRewardCode nvarchar(50) =null,
    @EstimatedSaving nvarchar(50) = null,
     @IsAirMilesMonday bit = False,
 @IsExpirymonthly bit = False,
 @IsPromoCodeEnabled nvarchar(50) = null,
  @IsLocked nvarchar(50) = null,
 @IsCompetition nvarchar(50) = null,
 @Sorting nvarchar(50) = null,
 @Tier nvarchar(50) = null
```

The way i am saving the data is below:

```
 UPDATE
    Rewards
SET
    SupplierId = @SupplierId,
    RewardCode = @RewardCode,
    RewardDesc = 'N'+@RewardDesc,
    RStartDate = @RStartDate,
    REndDate = @REndDate,
    RStatus = @RStatus,
    RCostPrice = @RCostPrice,
    RStocks = @RStocks,
    RewardTypeId = @RewardTypeId,
    RCategoryId = @RCategoryId,
    RProductDesc = 'N'+@RProductDesc,
    RTermsCond = 'N'+@RTermsCond,
    RRetailPrice = @RRetailPrice,
    PDCost = @PDCost,
    RFreight = @RFreight,
    TemplateId = @TemplateId,
    RTotalCost = @RTotalCost,
    DMId = @DMId,
    MinimumQuantity = @MinimumQuantity,
    RewardImageURL = @RewardImageURL,
    UpdateDate = @UpdateDate,
    Points = @Rpoints   ,
    ExpiryDateSetup = @ExpiryDateSetup,
          ExpiryNumberOfMonths = @ExpiryNumberOfMonths,
          MinimumStockCount = @minimumstockcount,
          RewardRelationId = @RewardRelationId ,
          ParentRewardCode = @ParentRewardCode ,
          EstimatedSaving = @EstimatedSaving,
          IsAirMilesMonday = @IsAirMilesMonday ,
          IsExpirymonthly = @IsExpirymonthly,
          IsPromoCodeEnabled = @IsPromoCodeEnabled,
          Islocked = @IsLocked ,
          IsCompetition = @IsCompetition ,
          Sorting = @Sorting,
          tier = @tier
WHERE
    RewardId = @RewardId;
```

******** EDIT ***********

The code used to call the SP is defined below:

```
Public Function Save(ByVal us As String, ByRef obrewardsold As cls_Rewards, ByRef obrewardsnew As cls_Rewards) As Boolean

    Dim sSQL As String
    Dim rtn As Boolean

    Dim rs As SqlDataReader = Nothing

    Try

        Save = True

        sSQL = "exec Rewards_upd"
        sSQL = sSQL & "  @SupplierId=" & gFixQuotes(SupplierId)

        sSQL = sSQL & ",  @RewardId=" & gFixQuotes(RewardId)
        sSQL = sSQL & " , @RewardCode=" & gFixQuotes(RewardCode)
        sSQL = sSQL & ", @RewardDesc=" & gFixQuotes(RewardDesc)
        sSQL = sSQL & ", @RStartDate=" & gFixQuotes(RStartDate)
        sSQL = sSQL & ", @REndDate=" & gFixQuotes(REndDate)
        sSQL = sSQL & ", @RStatus=" & gFixQuotes(RStatus)
        sSQL = sSQL & ", @RCostPrice=" & gFixQuotes(RCostPrice)
        sSQL = sSQL & ", @RRetailPrice=" & gFixQuotes(RRetailPrice)
        sSQL = sSQL & " ,@RFreight=" & gFixQuotes(RFreight)
        rtn = GetData(rs, sSQL)
```

Comment: Please read the following, should help: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90296/storing-japanese-characters-in-a-table

Comment: Actually, you are *breaking* the data - if the parameters are Unicode, ie nvarchar, you don't need to do anything. The line ` RewardDesc = 'N'+@RewardDesc,` though is concatenating an ASCII string that contains `N` with a string parameter, thus converting everything to ASCII

Comment: You can use like this **N''+@RewardId+''**

Comment: Neither ASP.NET nor SQL Server need any tricks to work with Unicode, as long as you don't *force* the use of ASCII. That means, that the table must use `nvarchar` columns, the query parameters must have an `nvarchar` type and the query itself should use those parameters, not string concatenation.

Comment: @HarisTasawar please post the code you use to call the stored procedure from ASP.NET. Do you actually use a parameterized query or do you use string concatenation?

Comment: @SqlZim this won't mangle the data, just prepend a useless `N`. The OP probably uses string concatenation to call the stored procedure instead of using a parameterized query

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, Yes you are correct, it is string Contact instead of Parameterized query.

Comment: @HarisTasawar don't do it then. You lose everything you gained by using parameters or a stored procedure. You are once again vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks and conversion problems like the one you just found. You don't need to "fix" any quotes that may appear in the input if you use a parameterized query either

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok, i will try to get to change the code to be parameterized instead of String Concatenation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither ASP.NET nor SQL Server need any tricks to work with Unicode. Both support Unicode natively. In all cases where strange characters appear, a conversion to ASCII was *forced*. Either the table field was varchar, or the parameter type, or the query contained ASCII string literals.

Sometimes, it may be that the source file itself was saved as ASCII, resulting in unexpected conversions before even the file was compiled. This particular problem disappeared when Visual Studio switched to UTF8 by default. I don't remember when that happened, it may have been a decade ago, maybe even earlier. It may still appear if you use a text editor that doesn't use UTF8 by default.

To store Japanese just do the same thing as with *every* other Unicode string - just make sure you use Unicode types.

First, ensure that the table uses `nvarchar` fields :

```
CREATE TABLE Rewards
(
    RewardId int not null primary key,
    RewardDesc nvarchar(50),
    ...
)
```

and all the stored procedure parameters are actually `nvarchar`. After that,  the only thing you need to do is create a parameterized query with `SqlDbType.NVarChar` parameters:

```
var cmd=new SqlCommand("Rewards_upd",connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;   
... 
// Assuming that RewardId is an integer 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@RewardId ", SqlDbType.Int).Value = RewardId;
// otherwise, parse it first. This will detect invalid input before executing the query
// cmd.Parameters.Add("@RewardId ", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(RewardId);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@RewardDesc ", SqlDbType.NVarChar,50).Value = RewardDesc;

var reader=cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

The stored procedure itself doesn't have to do anything to support Unicode input, simply use the correct types:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Rewards_upd (@RewardId int, @RewardDesc nvarchar(50)...)
AS
....
UPDATE Rewards
SET
    RewardDesc=@RewardDesc,
    ...
WHERE RewardId=@RewardId
```

Concatenating `N` with the Japanese string will prepend a useless `N` character. For example, the following query will return:

```
declare @text nvarchar(50)=N'如抜範浪偃壅國'

select @text, 'N' + @text

-------
如抜範浪偃壅國 N如抜範浪偃壅國
```

SQL Server will convert the `N` to Unicode and prepend it to `@text`.

On the other hand, if a *string literal* was used, the result would be mangled:

```
select '如抜範浪偃壅國'
-------
???????
```

If you see question marks instead of Japanese text, the most likely reason is that you use ASCII strings or literals somewhere. Most likely, you don't use parameterized queries to call the stored procedure and create a SQL string with concatenation instead

Comment: Using N'日本' to write SQL queries containing unicode literal strings is what I was looking for.